# Best and optimal query for ledger like / balance statement system

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: One for businesses and other for transactions.

```sql
create table businesses (id serial, name text);

create table transactions (id serial, src integer, dst integer, amount decimal);

insert into businesses (name) values ('John'); // id 1
insert into businesses (name) values ('Jane'); // id 2

-- Here, john gave 100 to jane
insert into transactions (src, dst, amount) values (1, 2, 100.0);

-- And here jane gave 50 to john
insert into transactions (src, dst, amount) values (2, 1, 50.0);

-- The balance between john and jane would be 50 positive for john and 50 negative for jane
```

So, the business giving money to the other is stored in the `src` column and the business receiving the money is stored in the `dst` column. This way I know who gave money to, and who received money from.

Now, suppose I would like to display this transactions as kind of ledger or a simple balance statement between two businesses, how the query would look like? Because it depends on which side of the transaction the business is on. If it's on side `A` it's an expense and if it is on side `B` its an income.

Comment: Interesting question. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Also, try to avoid using identifiers such as the word `from` that may be a reserved word.

Comment: "From" is a reserved word and will result in an error as it is used here. For that matter so if "To".  Both by Postgres and SQL Standard.

Comment: I've added some example data

Answer (score 1):

You would "unpivot" the data and aggregate:

```
select src, dest, sum(amount)
from ((select src, dest, amount
       from transactions
       where src < dest
      ) union all
      (select dest, src, -amount
       from transactions
       where src > desc
      )
     ) sd
group by src, dest
```